# Setting time of sms on Android 4.4

Tags: java, android, time, sms, system

I'm testing my app on Android 4.4.2. My app is the default sms app.

I use this code to write an sms:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", phoneNumber);
values.put("date", System.currentTimeMillis());
values.put("body", message);
values.put("type", inbox);
values.put("read", read);
context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms"), values);
```

The message was write correctly but its date is setting on 1/01/1970.

On Android 4.0.x, 4.1.x and 4.2.x this save the data correctly, but on android 4.4.2 no.

The problem is the `System.currentTimeMillis()`? How can i solve this?

Edit: The problem interesting only the original timestamp. The received timestamp remain set on 01/01/1970. Maybe i must add another paramether to save this other information?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you parsing `System.currentTimeMillis()` as date/time? `System.currentTimeMillis()` gives the time in milliseconds from 1/01/1970.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `date_sent` not `date`:

```
values.put("date_sent", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Otherwise, `date_sent` will be `0` which corresponds to `01/01/1970`!